# Azure DevOps: Ensure Production stage can only be released from the master branch of the repository

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I have a release pipeline with the usual stages

Dev -> Test -> Pre Production -> Production

I would like to know if there is a way to ensure that only the master branch can be promoted all the way to production to avoid releases from feature and develop branches ending on a production environment.

Comment: Are you using classic pipelines or YAML pipelines? What research have you done?

Comment: You can use the  branch filter on the `Continuous deployment Trigger` of the stage to only allow release from master branch. Please check out below answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## YAML Pipelines

If you're using a YAML-based pipeline, you can use the [Checks + Approval Gates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass) feature to add a branch policy check.

1. Create an [Environment for each deployment environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops)
2. Structure your YAML pipeline to use a *Deployment Job* that specifies the Environment

```
stages:
- stage: build
- stage: dev
- stage: test
- stage: preprod
- stage: prod
```

You can put conditions on the stages to ensure the branch conditions are met.

```
- stage: production
  dependsOn: preprod
  condition: |
    and(
      succeeded('preprod'),
      or(
        eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main'),
        startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release/'),
        startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/hotfix/')
      )         
    )
```

3. Ensure each stage that performs the deployment activities has a [Deployment Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops):

```
- deployment: deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy'
  environment: 'Production'
  strategy:
    runonce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - pwsh: Write-Host 'Deployment Steps go here!'
```

4. In your Production Environment, add the [*Branch Control* check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass#branch-control):

   [image: Branch Control]

## Classic Release Pipelines

If you're using a Classic Release pipeline, you can add artifact filters to prevent the pipeline from being queued, but these do not enforce that the Stage cannot be run manually or override these filters.

If you truly want to prevent the release, even if someone manually overrides the artifact filter, you could fail the build by checking that it is the correct branch in a script.

```
$currentBranch = "$(Release.Artifacts.MyAlias.SourceBranch)" 
if ( $currentBranch -ne "refs/heads/main" )
{
    Write-Host "##vso[task.logissue type=error]This release must originate from the main branch. Current branch: $currentBranch"
    Exit 1
}
```

[image: Fail build script]

Comment: There is a small typo in the example `eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch', 'refs/heads/main'),` where a closing bracket is missing. (**variables['Build.SourceBranch'**)

Comment: @bryanbcook in the classic solution, what is MyAlias exactly? how can I know my artifact name?

Comment: As per Predefined variables https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#general-artifact - the artifact associated with the Release is given a name. You can have multiple artifacts linked and you can rename them in the user-interface if desired.

Answer (score 3):

You can set a branch filter on the Continuous deployment Trigger, See below:

Click the highlighted **trigger** icon in the **Artifacts** section to open the trigger panel--> **Enabled** Continuous deployment Trigger--> Set the **branch filter** to only include master branch.

[image]

When you set your release pipeline Continuous  deployment Trigger as above. Only the artifacts generated from master branch can trigger the release pipeline.

You can also set an artifact filter for each stage to make sure only artifacts come from a specific branch can be deployed to this stage. See below:

[image]

You can check out [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/define-multistage-release-process?view=azure-devops) to learn more about classic CD pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

@paddingtonMike,

This is a core feature of ADO Release Pipelines, you can complete this many ways; however, the most common is by modifying the source of your artifact.

[image: New Artifact - Source Master Branch]

I highly recommend that you invest some time in learning ADO Release Pipelines. Here is a great resource to get started with:

[Learn - Create Release Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-release-pipeline/)

Comment: This just set master as the default branch to use. It does not stop you to from changing the artifact to one that was generated with a different branch in the repository

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to *prevent* a deployment from being created from a non-main branch. That said, Levi's answer will prevent a release from being created or deployed automatically. In addition to that, you can set up required reviewers on deployments which will guarantee no release can go out without the approval of a person who is authorized to deploy.

[image: Pre-deployment approval example]

(Specific section of the link Levi shared) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/define-multistage-release-process?view=azure-devops#add-pre-deployment-approvals